# Possible reasons of not showing up the view on SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I have my custom view that extends SurfaceView and here I have a spinner among others on it. I set its visibility to visible and invisible in turns but after one cycle of showing and hiding, next time it does not show up anymore. To verify what's wrong I draw on canvas text:

1. `spiner3.getVisibility()`
2. `spiner3.getX()`
3. `spiner3.getY()`

but nothing of these seem to be wrong I mean X and Y are on the within the screen and getVisibility returns `View.VISIBLE`. So what can be the other reason of not showing up if it is not visibility property and coordinations?

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround. In Activity that uses this view I added such code:

```
Handler mTimerHandler;
Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gra_layout);

    vg = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    refreshSpinner();
    ...
}


    private void refreshSpinner() {
    mTimerHandler = new Handler();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            mTimerHandler.post(() -> {
                    vg.invalidate();
            });
        }
    }, 0, 100);
}
```